# Factorial Triples

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

Lately I've come up with an interesting math problem to work at. I've been trying to find "factorial triples", or triples of numbers that satisfy
$$A!B!=C!$$
with $A,B \ne 1$. By playing around, I've noticed that the relationship is satisfied for all $A$, $B$, and $C$ in the form
$$A=K$$
$$B=K!-1$$
$$C=K!$$
And I've also proven the following, under the assumption that some $A,B$ exist satisfying the relationship with $C$:

- If $C-1$ is prime, then $C$ is a perfect factorial.
- If $C-k$ is prime, then some number in the form
  $$\frac{C!}{(C-n)!}, 1\le n\le k$$
  is a perfect factorial.
- C is not prime.

I have also conjectured (but I have not been able to prove) that $C$ cannot be a perfect power of a prime. This is my first question - can anyone give me a hint or two to start this proof?

The thing that bothers me is the triple
$$10!=7!6!$$
Because it does not satisfy the form that I had come up with. This one works because 
$$6!=8\cdot9\cdot10$$
and so I can conclude that if I can find other numbers of the form
$$H!=J\cdot(J+1)\cdot...\cdot(J+K)$$
then another possible form is
$$A=J-1$$
$$B=H$$
$$C=J+K$$
This is the second question. How can I find such $H,J,K$?

The third and final question is this: how to I prove that all factorial triples are in this form, or, if that is false, how do I find the other forms?

Thanks!

Comment: All cases must be examples of your $H,J,K$ type, with your first type being those with $K=0$

Comment: @AdamHughes  Your link broke.  Did you intend [24*(23!)-(24!)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=24*(23!)-(24!)) i.e. [(4)! * (4!-1)! - (4!)!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(4)!+*+(4!-1)!+-+(4!)!) ?